# Pre-fill a form via external file using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a way to let user upload a config file (text base, no encryption), then parsing that file (either line by line or separating fields by commas,...) to pre-fill textboxes field on the same page using javascript.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: And your question would be ... is this a good idea or how to do it?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use whatever your server-side technology is? Seeing as how the file is already uploaded I'd tend toward reading the file there and pre-setting the values of the form fields, rather than transferring the file contents back to the client and having javascript modify the form after the fact.

Comment: well there is a difficulty on the server side (Digi connect ME embedded server), that's why i try to get around it by doing the javascript client side.

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll have to handle the upload via a [ajax upload](http://www.webtoolkit.info/ajax-file-upload.html). Your javascript then can make an ajax call out to get the contents of the HTML file. What exactly are your need beyond this?

Comment: well in my config page of the site there are fields that the user can save to a file and restore it later to restore the config (kinda like backup/restore config of a router). But instead of actually commit the config, it just need to pre-fill textboxes on the page. The user will then have the ability to commit or modify couple fields then submit.